# Not able to force exit on Jenkins Build

Tags: shell, jenkins, exit-code

I've been having a lot of trouble with this so here goes.

I have a Jenkins build that executes the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
if [ 'grep -c "It misses" log' -gt 0 ];
then exit 1;
fi
```

I know that the grep returns 1 when it finds something and technically Jenkins should mark the build as failed on a non-zero exit, but the jenkins still marks it as a success.
The console output for the jenkins build when running the script is:

```
Started by user bla
[project_name] $ /bin/sh -x /var/tmp/hudson41276.sh
+ [ grep -c "It misses" log -gt 0 ] 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Could anybody give me a hand and point out what I'm missing here?

Thanks,
CJ

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want the job to fail if "It misses" is not found in file "log". You can do this by not using the -c option of grep, just redirect the output like this:

```
grep "It misses" log > /dev/null
```

Grep will return 0 if it finds the phrase, and the job will succeed. If it does not find the phrase, grep will return 1, and the job will fail. If you want it the other way around (fail if it does find the phrase) just use grep -v. $? is your friend when you want to be sure of the exit status of a shell command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
grep -c "It misses" log
```

`set -e`: Exit at the first error.

`grep -c 'arg'`: Exit 1 if nothing was grepped.

Comment: i tried it but now it just says 'grep -c "It misses" log: not found' so it fails either way.if something was found it returns one from what i noticed no?

Comment: The problem should come from Jenkins, not sh/bash. I can't help you at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your script, not Jenkins. The part of your script where you attempt to compare the exit code of grep looks like this:

```
if [ 'grep -c "It misses" log' -gt 0 ] ...
```

This will not even execute grep. In fact, it is simply comparing a string to a number.

You were probably attempting to do:

```
if [ `grep -c "It misses" log` -gt 0 ] ...
```

Note the use of backticks (`). Shell will execute grep and replace the backticks with the *output* of grep.

Bonus item: the condition in the `if` statement is actually a command that gets executed and its exit code determines where the execution will continue. So... why not use the `grep` command and it's useful exit code as the condition? (`grep` will exit with code 0 when it finds matches.)

```
if grep "It misses" log; then
    exit 1
fi
```

It's shorter, much more readable and ever performs better because it does not need to execute so many commands.

Such a short `if` statement could even be replaced with a one-liner:

```
grep "It misses" log && exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

By default jenkins start shell with -e, so it exists at first error.

You could turn it off by

```
set +e
do failing task..
```